# Controlling catalina_home in liferay eclipse tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, liferay

I have a development system ( linux-Liferay6-tomcat6-Eclipse Helios) that I have version-controlled in SVN. When I roll it out for a new developer in what amounts to a fresh installation, the paths for the tomcat server are wrong because they were written in various places as absolute paths reflecting my desktop.

It looks to me that I could modify catalina.sh or startup.sh to fix this problem, or part of it maybe, but I'd rather have a fix that leaves Tomcat unmolested. I could also require developers to set CATALINA_HOME, but that would break any other tomcat installations they might have ( my own situation in fact).

For instance, maybe a custom Ant script that figures out the path and sets CATALINA_HOME just for the shell thats running this particular Tomcat? Is there a way to do this in the Eclipse IDE, I looked but don't quite see it?

Ideas?

John Fisher

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ant and the liferay plugins sdk, you're supposed to create a build.${username}.properties file in the root folder of the plugins sdk. (substitute ${username} with the name you log in to your OS). In this you override the location of your appserver, e.g. tomcat. Take a look at build.properties. Though you're not supposed to change this file, you can copy the one interesting line (note: it's preconfigured for tomcat) and use it for the appropriate settings.

This way you'll have a per-user setting for the required value.

The server (if you require to start it in eclipse) is to be created in each eclipse instance, independent of each other. The Liferay IDE plugins for eclipse can help you with setting this up.

As I expect the server to be modified by everybody on a frequent basis, I never share the server "project" in version control, but keep it strictly local. It's easily recreated if lost.

Comment: Very helpful Olaf, I'll look at that. Since I wrote this I have discovered even more problems using Eclipse from an archive. It may well be that its better just to archive the original Eclipse tarball and do a complete setup on each developer's machine. It's not hard to set up.